# taking mean in trees predictions

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, random-forest

How to change class vote in tree_vote from taking the majority to taking mean (average) in trees predictions?

```
def tree_vote(forest, data):

    # add all predictions in the list
    predictions = []
    for tree in forest:
        predictions.append(predict(data, tree))

    # create the list of predictions for each object
    predictions_per_object = list(zip(*predictions))

    # The final prediction for each object is the one voted for by the majority of the trees
    voted_predictions = []
    for obj in predictions_per_object:
        voted_predictions.append(max(set(obj), key=obj.count))
    return voted_predictions

train_answers = tree_vote(my_forest_1, train_data)
test_answers = tree_vote(my_forest_1, test_data)
```

Comment: 1) The argument `forest, data` are in no use in your function. 2) Post the content of sample `obj`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
 I has increased the code in the description. I published all `def tree_vote` and the example of calling this function

Comment: what's the contents of `set(obj)` ?